# Web Scraping with Login MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to use a method I saw in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGw6r5GVA5g&ab_channel=WiseOwlTutorials!) to access data in
https://my.powerdiary.com/Profile/Client/Search

However, requires a login. From what I found online it seems very hard to understand how to login to that page.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HTMLTest()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim HTMLInputUser As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInputPass As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Dim HTMLRoles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRole As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://my.powerdiary.com/Profile/Client/Search", False, "email", "password"
    XMLReq.send
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "-" & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    
    Set HTMLRoles = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("form-section-title mt10")
        
    Debug.Print HTMLRoles.Length
    
    For Each HTMLRole In HTMLRoles
        Debug.Print HTMLRole.tagName, HTMLRole.innerText, HTMLRole.innerHTML
    Next HTMLRole
    
End Sub
```

The screenshot is from the page after login. So, trying to check if I’ve logged in by returning those elements.
[image]

Comment: I added the code I've used but the elements returned are from the login page, which I assume it means I haven't logged in. As I mentioned, I'm not experience in coding so, not sure if what I've done is correct. I just tried to follow those Youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to offer any solution when there is no credentials to test with, so the solution I'm trying to privide is hypothetical.

According to the dev tools, you have to fill in the value of the following three keys before sending them as parameter with post requests:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: 
UserName: 
Password: 
RememberMe: false
MobileSite: false
```

You need to send a `get` requests first to collect the value of token. Once the fields are duly filled in, you need to encode them.

This is how the script should look like:

```
Sub ScrapeAfterLogIn()
    Const logInUrl = "https://my.powerdiary.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2FClient%2FSearch"
    Const contentPage = "https://my.powerdiary.com/Profile/Client/Search"
    
    Dim oHttp As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, formData$, sToken$
    Dim sUser$, sPass$, sResp$

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    sUser = ""     'your username
    sPass = ""     'your password

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", logInUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        sToken = Html.querySelector("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").getAttribute("value")
        formData = "__RequestVerificationToken=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sToken) & "&UserName=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sUser) & "&Password=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sPass) & "&RememberMe=false&MobileSite=false"

        .Open "POST", logInUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (formData)
        
        .Open "GET", contentPage, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        sResp = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print sResp
End Sub
```

If for some reason you don't get content from [the desired page](https://my.powerdiary.com/Profile/Client/Search), you wanna use cookies within the script to achieve that.

Comment: Oh man!! It did work! The elements are from the page I'm interested. Amazing! Hey, do you mind add some comments on the code for my understanding? I did created a trial account so I could share it with you but I don't think I need it.

Comment: I'll use the code tomorrow and I'll get back with more comments. Thank you SOOOOOOO much!

Comment: I have a question if you please can help me understand. First time I open the file and run it, it seems it goes past the login page. If I run the same module (I'm testing how to get the html elements I'm interesting) I get a Runtime error 91 at `sToken`. If I close it and reopen, on the first run no errors but on the 2nd run I get the same error. Does it mean that once I login with your code I can create different modules and explore the elements? Hopefully I make some sense...